# Error after installing Cygwin: bash: bad substitution: no closing "`" in

Tags: bash, cygwin

After installing Cygwin on my Windows machine, I was immediately presented with the following error after launching the application:

> ```
> bash: bad substitution: no closing "`" in...
> ```

This error prevents me from using the shell.

I am running Windows 10 and GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: There's probably something wrong in one of your shell startup files like `.bashrc`.